# Carriage return character does not render HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, jhipster

I have a angular controller that is pulling data off a restful api and feeding it to a HTML page.
Among many fields, one of them is actually text (which comes from a network device) which is a list of `Filename`:`Filedata`. `Filedata` is actually formatted data.
Sample data:

`'AGGR-STATUS-V.txt': 'Aggr State Status Options\r\n aggr root, nosnap=off, \r\n mirrored, \r\n 32-bit, \r\n , \r\n , \r\n no_delete_log=off, \r\n hybrid_enabled=off, \r\n , \r\n thorough_scrub=off\r\n\r\n\t\tVolumes: vol0\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr0/plex0: online, normal, active\r\n RAID group /aggr0/plex/: normal, block checksums\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr0/plex2: online, active\r\n, block checksums\r\n\r\n, \r\n mirrored raid_lost_write=on, ignore_inconsistent=off, \r\n 32-bit snapmirrored=off, resyncsnaptime=60, \r\n rlw_on fs_size_fixed=off, \r\n, no_delete_log=off, \r\n , \r\n , \r\n free_space_realloc=off, raid_cv=on, \r\n thorough_scrub=off\r\n\r\n\t\tVolumes: vol1, nk_srvtreasury03, nk_srvtreasury04\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr1/plex0: online, normal, active\r\n RAID group /aggr1/plex0/rg0: normal, block checksums\r\n RAID group /aggr1/plex0/rg1: normal, block checksums\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr1/plex1: online, normal, active\r\n RAID group /aggr1/plex1/rg0: normal, block checksums\r\n RAID group /aggr1/plex1/rg1: normal, block checksums\r\n\r\n aggr2 online raid_dp, aggr nosnap=off, raidtype=raid_dp, raidsize=11, \r\n mirrored raid_lost_write=on, ignore_inconsistent=off, \r\n 32-bit snapmirrored=off, resyncsnaptime=60, \r\n rlw_on fs_size_fixed=off, snapshot_autodelete=on, \r\n lost_write_protect=on, no_delete_log=off, \r\n ha_policy=cfo, hybrid_enabled=off, \r\n percent_snapshot_space=5%, \r\n free_space_realloc=off, raid_cv=on, \r\n thorough_scrub=off\r\n\r\n\t\tVolumes: vol2, st_srvtreasury03, st_srvtreasury04\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr2/plex0: online, normal, active\r\n RAID group /aggr2/plex0/rg0: normal, block checksums\r\n RAID group /aggr2/plex0/rg1: normal, block checksums\r\n\r\n Plex /aggr2/plex1: online, normal, active\r\n RAID group /aggr2/plex1/rg0: normal, block checksums\r\n RAID group /aggr2/plex1/rg1: normal, block checksums\r\n\r\n'`

This is a variable in the angularjs (`{{vm.alert.alerts}}`) and displays as is in the HTML page. I want the HTML to honor the carriage return and new line and tabs. 
So far I have tried preceding `<pre><code></pre></code>`. But haven't been able to display it properly. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

No need for `<pre>` tags. You can style the line breaks with `white-space:pre-wrap` css attribute.

```
<code style="white-space:pre-wrap;">{{vm.alert.alerts}}</code>
```

Although it's better to have a CSS class instead of inline styles.

```
<code class="pre-wrapped">{{vm.alert.alerts}}</code>

/* in the css file */
.pre-wrapped {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: I tried with just the `white-space:pre-wrap;` though it is a little better to read, it is still rendering `\r\n` and `\t` as just characters

Comment: I used Jhipster to scaffold my app, if that matters. (I know they mess with the css files, not sure what to look for)

Comment: Maybe try `<p class="pre-wrapped" ng-bind-html="vm.alert.alerts"></p>` if you're using angular 1.x, from memory you'll need to include ngSanitize.